# Structural equation models without circular definition of latent variables

Tags: bayesian, structural-equation-modeling, pymc, stan

I'm trying to perform Bayesian structural equation modeling in Python and PyMC3, but I think the problem is similar for most probabilistic progamming languages, include JAGS, Stan, etc.

SEMs are often defined using equations like these:

$\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{\nu}+\boldsymbol{\Lambda}\boldsymbol{\eta}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\\
\boldsymbol{\eta}=\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{B}\boldsymbol{\eta}+\boldsymbol{\zeta}\\
\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\sim\mathrm{MvNormal}\left(0, \boldsymbol{\Theta}\right)\\
\boldsymbol{\zeta}\sim\mathrm{MvNormal}\left(0, \boldsymbol{\Psi}\right)
\end{equation}$

As you can see, the latent variables in $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ are defined in terms of themselves. The model makes sense because $\boldsymbol{B}$ is a sparse, invertible, non-symmetric matrix that defines paths between latent variables, but I'm not sure how to code this in practice. Can the second equation be re-written/expanded to so that the definition is no longer "circular" and therefore more amenable to coding?

I realize that under SEM one usually marginalizes out $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ and so the problem is moot. However, I think it should be possible to code it up with $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ explicitly sampled.

Comment: What makes the original form difficult for coding? I fail to see

Comment: Defining a variable as a function of itself, which hasn't been defined yet. `x = x` won't work in most programming languages.

Comment: I wouldn't define it like that. For instance, in c++ you could do f(**f()), in Python you could pass a list of functions references. It's also more generic than naming concrete functions, this way you can pass any functions

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to define it that way. This is more of a question of the mathematical notation anyhow. The accepted answer perfectly understood the issue and provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B})$ is invertible, we can rewrite the $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ equation as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\eta} &= \boldsymbol{\alpha}+\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\eta}+\boldsymbol{\zeta} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
\boldsymbol{\eta} - \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\eta} &= \boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\zeta} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B})\boldsymbol{\eta} &= \boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\zeta} \\
&\Updownarrow \\
\boldsymbol{\eta} &= (\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{B})^{-1} (\boldsymbol{\alpha}+\boldsymbol{\zeta}) \\
\end{align}
$$

Where $\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix with the appropriate shape.